# AS3 Mouse_Over Getting Stuck

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent, mouseover

I have many buttons being populated on the stage. They are all movieclips with an on and off state on frame one and 2. The problem is when you mouse over the buttons quickly sometimes it gets stuck on the over state. Is there something i am missing?

```
public class SimpleRollOverButton extends MovieClip
{
    private var _selected:Boolean;

    public function SimpleRollOverButton()
    {
        // EVENTS
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick, false, 0, true);
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onMouseOver);
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onMouseOut);

        enable();


    }
    //
    // PUblic functions
    //
    public function enable():void
    {

        this.selected = false;
        this.gotoAndStop(1);
        this.mouseEnabled = this.mouseChildren = true;
        this.buttonMode = true;


    }
    public function disable():void
    {   

        this.mouseEnabled = this.mouseChildren = false;
        this.buttonMode = false;
    }
    public function onState():void
    {
        this.disable();
        this.selected = true;

        this.gotoAndStop(2);

    }
    public function offState():void
    {
        this.enable();
    }

    //
    // Private Functions
    //
    protected function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        onState();
    }
    protected function onMouseOver(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        this.gotoAndStop(2);
    }
    protected function onMouseOut(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        this.gotoAndStop(1);    
    }

    //
    // ACCESSORS
    //
    public function get selected():Boolean
    {
        return _selected;
    }

    public function set selected(value:Boolean):void
    {
        _selected = value;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a listener to the stage or to the MovieClip, which contains the buttons (if it has a background, and its not transparent):

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, turnThemOff); 
function turnThemOff(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    for (var i:int=0; i<yourButtons.length; i++) yourButtons[i].gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

If you move the mouse quickly away from the SWF movie, this could help:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, turnThemOff);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The issue i am having with this answer is that there are a bunch of other loaded in assets that also have event listeners on them. If there were only these buttons on the stage this would be a fantastic way of approaching this. Would you know why the MOUSE_OUT just isn't firing? Should i be removing and adding the roll over and roll out listeners when needed instead?

Comment: It happens only when you move the mouse very fast? Try to increase the framerate. See if it happens with a framerate about 50fps.